# How do I create a laravel artisan command?

Tags: php, laravel-4, namespaces

I want to create the commands `order:process` and `order:lock`. So far, I have figured out that I need to run `php artisan command:make process --namespace=order` to create the order:process class file. Then I need to set the $name value in the app/commands/process.php to 'order:process'. This is where I'm stuck.

I think I need to add something to app/start/artisan.php to make the command usable, but I can't figure out what. I've tried `Artisan::add(new order\process);` and `Artisan::add(new process);`, but neither of these work. What do I need to do, to get my new commands available to be run from the command line? I know the problem is to do with the use of a namespace, but I can't find any documentation on artisan commands that use namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

For laravel 5.0

```
php artisan make:console Foo --command=foo:do
```

Edit your commands located in app/Console/Commands/Foo.php

Then register your commands by adding an entry to app/Console/Kernel.php

```
protected $commands = [
    'Cloudlite\Console\Commands\Inspire',
    'Cloudlite\Console\Commands\EmailParser',
    'Cloudlite\Console\Commands\Foo',
];
```

You can now run like the following (example default option, edit Foo.php)

```
php artisan foo:do example=1
```

Answer (score 1):

First create them with *artisan* command

```
php artisan command:make OrderProcessCommand --command=order:process
php artisan command:make OrderLockCommand --command=order:lock
```

Edit your commands located in `app/commands`

Then register your commands in `app/start/artisan.php`

```
Artisan::add(new OrderProcessCommand);
Artisan::add(new OrderLockCommand);
```

Answer (score 0):

I still have no idea how to use namespaces, but I have figured this part out.

The answer is, to use `php artisan command:make orderProcessCommand`, and register that with `Artisan::add(new orderProcessCommand);`. The in orderProcessCommand.php, set the $name to `order:process`. Artisan will read the class as directed by the registration command, but make it available to be called as described in the $name field.